# SSL errors when pushing and pulling with git

Tags: git, ssl

so i have an error that is preventing me from pushing/pulling any of my repositories regardless of where they are on my system.  I'm not really familiar with SSL and certificate type things.  This is a Linux Centos 7 machine.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
[user@computer ~/location]$ git push
fatal: unable to access 'https://user@bitbucket.org/user/repository.git/': SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length.
```

Comment: Your origin address might be wrong. What do you get when you do :  git remote show origin ?

Comment: i get the same error as above "fatal: unable to access 'https://user@bitbucket.org/user/repository.git/': SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research on the topic.  This wasn't a problem with git or a problem with the bitbucket.org website.  It was related to the firewall and proxy settings related to a VPN.  not much help i know